# What is standard approach to implement login page common across different organizational websites?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt

I want to develop a "common" login page for all different websites that our organization offers. That is user should be able to log in only with a single username and password and be able to access all different organizational sites allowed to him.

I can develop a React login page. But what is the "standard or common" approach followed in the Industry to make this login page common across different sites? Should I do some kind of redirection if the user is not logged in and is trying to access a webpage requiring being logged in? If yes, how? If not, what else?

**Some more details**

User can hit different organizational site based on his role. For example, organization will have separate portal for international candidates applying for admission to one of the course and hence will have to use username-password. Existing students / professors / staff have separate portals and may opt for LDAP login or Google login or username-password.

I feel having single login page for all of them will be good. Clicking login on these different portals should take all of them to login page which should allow all these different types of login.

Or am wrong with having single login page?

Comment: What I understand is that you want to create only one login page through which users can log in to any organizational website ? Further, do you want to create a login form on the main organization website or to have the ability to display it on all websites ?

Comment: User can hit different organizational site based on his role. For example, organization will have separate portal for international candidates applying for admission to one of the course and hence will have to use username-password. Existing students / professors / staff have separate portals and may opt for LDAP login or Google login or username-password. 

I feel having single login page for all of them will be good. Clicking login on these different portals should take all of them to login page which should allow all these different types of login.Or Am wrong with havin single login page?

Comment: You have already mentioned a number of different technologies; have you researched them and already ruled out or favoured some based on your research? Do you have existing authentication infrastructure to work with, or are you creating all this from scratch, including the authentication for all those services?

Comment: @deceze I guess the question is about the approach to follow and I believe these approaches can be implemented in different technologies, right? This is development from scratch. Only reactjs and spring boot is finalized. Rest of the technologies I am researching. I have come up with this combination: TypeScript, OAuth2, webpack, redux, axios, react router and MaterialUI. I will be glad if you can suggest any more preferable alternative to any of these. I have put the "related" tags so that devs worked in "related" area can have a look at the question.

Comment: I'm more talking about OAuth, LDAP etc. These are different approaches to centralised authentication. Have you researched those?

Comment: sorry for late reply... what exactly you want me to explore about this? I am going to use spring boot at server side. So spring security provides corresponding packages for both OAuth and LDAP. Not yet sure if I need to be aware about something at client side for implementing OAuth and LDAP ...